# Allow several ip address for admin login using htaccess files

Tags: .htaccess, security, web

I am doing one application in php and i want to make the admin login secure for that i need to make the admin login functionality only from one ip address.

So how can it be possible, please reply your help will  be appreciated

Answer (score 4):

in your .htaccess file

order deny,allow

deny from all

allow from your ip

Comment: Thanks Haris thanks, this is one way to do that but can we do it using htaccess programming